# 405 Method Not Allowed Error in AJAX POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I'm trying to save some user inputs thru Ajax POST but I keep having this error

> 405 method not allowed.

```js
var formData = {
  category: $("#category").val(),
  assetType: $("#assetType").val(),
  description: $("#description").val(),
}
console.log(formData);

$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  url: '/add-asset',
  data: formData,
  type: "POST",
  enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  success: function(data) {
    if (data.status == 1) {
      openAlertDialog("Success", data.message, "Continue");
    } else {
      openAlertDialog("Error", data.message, "Continue", "");
    }
  },
  error: function(data) {
    openAlertDialog("Error", data.message, "Continue", "");
  },
});
```

Controller Code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add-asset", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String addAsset(@ModelAttribute AssetCategory as, Principal principal) {
    as.setAssetID(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    as.setCreatedBy(principal.getName());

    JsonObject result = new JsonObject();

        assetService.save(as);
        result.addProperty("result", "Success");
        result.addProperty("status", 1);
        result.addProperty("message", "Changes Saved.");

    return result.toString();
}
```

I can retrieve the user input but can't pass it to my controller.

The Inner Source in Chrome

[image]

Comment: It's not the AJAX request doing this, as that's calling `/add-asset`, yet the error is coming from `/manage-assets`. I would assume that you're making the AJAX request when a `form` is submit using a GET request, but you've not prevented that form submission.

Comment: I have a GET request for /manage-assets. Im using it to populate my Data Table. Inside the manage-assets.html has a form that I'm using to add some assets.So the GET request for populating the Data table is preventing the form submission?

Comment: Possibly, but it's hard to say definitively given the information in the question. In any case the issue is because you're sending a request with a different HTTP request verb than the server expects for that endpoint

Comment: How are you calling your add-asset POST? via a button click?  Make sure the button is `<button type='button'>` and return false from the click handler (to be sure).

Comment: Edit: I've run again the code using add-asset as the URL but still it's giving a 405. I'm using a button and calling it by onclick.

Comment: What do you see in server logs? What server is running the code? Are you sure it's even reaching your Spring code, or could it be being blocked higher up?

Comment: However, I suspect the issue is that the AJAX data being sent doesn't match the Spring method signature, so it's not finding a method at all to respond to the POST.

Comment: I already fixed it by creating a token for the AJAX POST. I'll post later the solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it by putting this code in my form

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" th:value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

it seems that its looking for a token so I've put a hidden input in my form.